# boost/endian: arithmetic types cannot be packed (non-POD)?

Tags: c++, boost, endianness

Boost/endian defines macros which assure its arithmetic types are POD, as explained [in the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html#buffers_compilation). However, no matter how much I try, this MWE

```c
#define BOOST_ENDIAN_NO_CTORS
#define BOOST_ENDIAN_FORCE_PODNESS
#include<boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
struct __attribute__((packed)) Foo{
    boost::endian::little_uint32_t a;
};
```

produces this warning (using g++ 11.3):

```
warning: ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field ‘boost::endian::little_uint32_t Foo::a’
    5 |         boost::endian::little_uint32_t a;
      |                                        ^
```

How can I make the `boost::endian::little_uint32_t` truly a POD?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/dqnY4ooWj I guess your real TU includes boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp prior `#define BOOST_ENDIAN_NO_CTORS`